# Cannot resolve symbol "packageName" inside build files after changing from "compile" to "implementation"

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, implementation

Hi I wanted to address a possible bug introduced in the new Android's gradle,

How to produce it:
when you have a library you use inside your project that also uses implementations (like google APIs) you are asked to change from "compile" to "implementation"

The problem: after doing this, in my case it compiled fine in "make APK" but failed to compile as "signed APK", the log just says "resolve your warnings" and the warning are "cannot resolve XXX package" "cannot resolve XXX class" but produced by imported libraries/apis inside "build" folder.

This is caused by a possible bug when doing a double "implementation" from the API to your library and from the library to your main module/app. By the way this didn't happens when using "compile"

SOLUTION: my work around (not definitive solution) is to move the classes that use those specific implementations to the main module/app inside a temporary Helper file and implement the APIs directly into the module/app.

Let me know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION: my work around (not definitive solution) is to move the classes that use those specific implementations to the main module/app inside a temporary Helper file and implement the APIs directly into the module/app.

SOLUTION: I found somewhere else that you can solve this by using API instead of implementation in the library's dependencies, like this:

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
}
```

Let me know if there is a better solution.